# How to copy a certificate from one Azure Key Vault to another?

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-keyvault

I am trying to copy a certificate from one key vault into another without persisting it on local machine. I looks like Azure KeyVault CLI only supports file-based certificate import like this:

```
# download cert 
az keyvault certificate download --file $certFileName --vault-name $sourceAkv -n $certName

# import cert 
az keyvault certificate import --file $certFileName --vault-name $destAkv -n $certName
```

Is there any way to pass an object or string instead? In Azure Powershell module this is possible:

```
Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $DestinationVaultName -Name $CertificateName -CertificateString $secretText.SecretValueText
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Any more questions? Or if it's helpful you can accept it.

Comment: So you're looking for a solution with Azure CLI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to just import the certificate context to the Azure Keyvault as you say. It only has the parameter dependant on the certificate file.

Answer (score 6):

I found something like this can work in PowerShell to export the certificate and key as an object, then import it into another keyvault without having to save it as a temporary PFX file.

```
$CertName = 'mycert'
$SrcVault = 'mysourcekeyvault'
$DstVault = 'mydestinationkeyvault'
$cert = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $SrcVault -Name $CertName
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $SrcVault -Name $cert.Name
$secretValueText = '';
$ssPtr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secret.SecretValue)
try {
    $secretValueText = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($ssPtr)
}
finally {
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($ssPtr)
}
$secretByte = [Convert]::FromBase64String($secretValueText)
$x509Cert = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$x509Cert.Import($secretByte, "", "Exportable,PersistKeySet")
Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $DstVault -Name $CertName -CertificateCollection $x509Cert
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure Key Vault SDKs. This is a way to do it in C#:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates;

var vaultUri = GetRequiredEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT_URI");
var secretName = GetRequiredEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT_SECRET");
var toVaultUri = GetRequiredEnvironmentVariable("TO_KEYVAULT_URI");

var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached);
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(vaultUri), credential);
var secret = client.GetSecret(secretName).Value;
var toVaultClient = new CertificateClient(new Uri(toVaultUri), credential);
toVaultClient.ImportCertificate(new ImportCertificateOptions(secretName, Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value)));

string GetRequiredEnvironmentVariable(string name)
{
    string? value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        throw new Exception($"Missing required environment variable '{name}'.");
    }
    return value;
}
```

There is a NuGet package for corresponding to each of those using statements. The identity used will `Get` permissions in `Access policies` to both secrets and certificates. `Import` certificate permissions are required for the destination Key Vault.